# Why Robot mouse clicks won't work when mouse is focused on a full screen program?

Tags: java, fullscreen, awtrobot, mouseclick-event

I have this program that constantly monitors the center pixel of my screen. If the color of the center pixel changes it uses the `Robot` class to fire of essentially a click. I can turn it on/off through F9/F10 respectively. It works pretty well when I run the program.

My problem is that when I run the program and **ALT + TAB** to a fullscreen program (ex. PC Game) the clicks cease to work. Any idea why this is happening?

```
public class PixelBot implements NativeKeyListener{

    private final Robot colorBot;

    private boolean running = true;

    private int lastPixelValue = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new PixelBot());
    }

    public PixelBot() throws AWTException {
        this.colorBot = new Robot();
        this.runInBackground();
    }

    private void checkPixel() throws AWTException {
        Rectangle areaOfInterest = getAreaOfInterest();
        BufferedImage image = colorBot.createScreenCapture(areaOfInterest);

        int clr = image.getRGB(0, 0);
        if (clr != lastPixelValue) {
            int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int blue = clr & 0x000000ff;
            System.out.println("\nPixel color changed to: Red: " + red + ", Green: " + green + ", Blue: " + blue);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            lastPixelValue = clr;
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        } else {
            System.out.print(".");
        }
    }

    private Rectangle getAreaOfInterest() {
        // screen size may change:
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        // half of center of screen, minus 1 pixel to be captured:
        int centerPointX = (int)(screenSize.getWidth() / 2 - 1);
        int centerPointY = (int)(screenSize.getHeight() / 2 - 1);
        Point centerOfScreenMinusOnePixel = new Point(centerPointX, centerPointY);
        //System.out.println(centerPointX + " "  + centerPointY);
        return new Rectangle(centerOfScreenMinusOnePixel, new Dimension(1, 1));
    }

    private void runInBackground() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if(running){
                        try {
                            checkPixel();
                        } catch (AWTException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.running = false;
    }

    public void start() {
        this.running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
         if(NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()).equals("F9")){
             stop();
         }
         else if(NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()).equals("F10")){
             start();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the clicks supposed to happen inside of the game?

Comment: In theory I was thinking it should happen anywhere, so yep

Comment: Have you already debugged your program? Does it detect the changed pixel? Can it successfully simulate the click (without beeing recognized by the focused program) or is there an exception? Does your game get the simulated mouse click if it is in window mode?

Comment: The game is most likely either blocking the input or it is not handling how you expect then. I don't think this is an answerable question.

Comment: There's no bugs in the program. It detects the pixel changes (whenever there is one) since I output the RGB values when it changes, else it just keeps writing periods "." as it runs. It simulates a click and I have tested that (moved the chrome minimize window to the middle of my screen). I have not tested the game in Windowed mode but I'm not sure how to do that part (on the game side of things)

Comment: If you haven't tested it with that game in window mode, then how do you know that the problem is the full screen?

Comment: @Tom I assumed it's full screen because everything that I've tested on were windowed, just not that game specifically

Comment: Well, then you do more tests on that game. Maybe it is like @jkeuhlen said: the problem is the game, not your program. Btw: you shouldn't instantly release the mouse key after pressing it. Some programs might need some time (in my experience round about 30 to 60 ms) to register the mouse click.

Comment: Along the same lines of what @Tom said,  if you are trying to use this to "cheat" in a game, the game could possibly have protections in place to stop you from using a simulated mouse.

Comment: @Tom I'm new this using this class, how would I make a delay, and update, it still doesn't work even when windowed. So is it blocking the click?

Comment: @HuangChen You could simply add a `Thread.sleep` between clicking and releasing the mouse button.

Comment: @Tom ok thank you, do you recommend closing the question then?

Comment: It is up to you. If you think a future reader can learn from it, then keep it. If you think otherwise and it doesn't help you either, then you can delete it.

Comment: I definitely think someone can learn from it, plus maybe someone even can help with a work around. Thank you for your help :)